# Why am I not able to create stub in new Java 1.8? Then what should I have to do for lookup of remote object without stub?

Tags: java, rmi, classnotfoundexception

> Warning: generation and use of skeletons and static stubs for JRMP
>   is deprecated. Skeletons are unnecessary, and static stubs have
>   been superseded by dynamically generated stubs. Users are
>   encouraged to migrate away from using rmic to generate skeletons and static
>   stubs. See the documentation for `java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject`.

```
error: Class serverside.Serverside not found.
```

1 error

Comment: -1 for the title in uppercase , uppercase = shout

Comment: And what happens when you saw the documentation for UnicastRemoteObject that caused all this SHOUTING? Have you read it at all? -1

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is answered in the documentation referred to by the error message quoted.

Comment: got it...and solved the error thanks

Comment: Please close this thread.

Answer (score 2):

> **Deprecation Note:** Support for static generation of Java Remote Method Protocol (JRMP) stubs and skeletons has been deprecated. Oracle recommends that you use dynamically generated JRMP stubs instead, eliminating the need to use this tool for JRMP-based applications. See the java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject specification at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/rmi/server/UnicastRemoteObject.html for further information.

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/rmic.html

Answer (score 0):

> Why am I not able to create stub in new Java 1.8?

You are.

> Then what should I have to do for lookup of remote object without stub?

With or without a stub, the lookup code is the same.

> See the documentation for java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.

Good idea. Do that.

> error: Class serverside.Serverside not found.

This error message has nothing to do with stubs.

In short your question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Not helpful. He is asking to solve the issue, not read up on UnicastRemoteObject

Comment: @Setrino There is no issue to solve. All he's done is cite the documentation you referred to, so he is already reading it, and then an unrelated error message. No code, no deployment information, no actual question. I've answered the question implied in his title.

Answer (score 0):

for java > 1.4 you can not start it statically but you can start stub dynamically by using the java.rmi.registry

```
package rmiEcho;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;

/**
 *
 * @author hamza
 */
public class regServ {
    public static void main(String [] args) throws RemoteException, AlreadyBoundException, MalformedURLException{
        LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
        echoInt objEcho = new EchoImp();
        System.out.print(objEcho.toString());
        Naming.bind("echoMsg", objEcho);
    }
}
```

Comment: Cannot start what statically? and what does 1.4 have to do with it? If you're referring to the Registry, you can *still* start it from the command line, if that's what you mean by 'static'. And if you're referring to starting *stubs' statically, this is meaningless. You never could start a stub, and the code you've posted doesn't do so. So you're either wrong or incomprehensible.